# Defining aliases for setf functions in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252539/defining-aliases-to-standard-common-lisp-functions?s=2%7C1.7428), an alias to a function can be created like so:

```
(defun some-function () ...)
(setf (fdefinition 'sfunc) #'some-function)
```

But:

```
(defun some-function () ...)
(defun (setf some-function) () ...)
(setf (fdefinition 'sfunc) #'some-function)

> (setf (sfunc) ...)
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: (SETF SFUNC)
```

The alias is not created for the setf function. How can an alias be created for a setf function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(setf (fdefinition '(setf sfunc)) (fdefinition '(setf some-function)))
```